# Fancybox3 Youtube video onload and autostart

Tags: fancybox

I have an little site with a video. Its a YouTube Video.

But if fancybox show up, the video it will not autostart.

Here is my code:

```
<section class="contact bg-primary" id="video">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Videoteaser</h2>

      <a data-fancybox data-width="640" data-small-btn="true" data-height="360" class="btn btn-outline2 btn-xl js-scroll-trigger"ata-small-btn="true" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkCbpgUpkMo">Videoteaser</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

To open up automatically I have this little JS on the bottom of the site:

```
$('[data-fancybox]').eq(0).trigger('click');
```

The Problem ist that the video do not autostart. No matter if I click on the button or if I use the little JS to autoopen the fancybox.

Only after klicken the Play-Button the Video do start.

How can I make ist autostart?

Comment: I use Safari on Mac. You're right, in Mozilla it will autostart. But wehen I go on the fancybox Website (with Safari) the example Video do autostart.

Comment: In Chrome it do Autostart. But not in Safari (Mac). But on the FancyApps-Site it do autostart.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Chrome, right? Then the answer is simple - it will not start due to `Autoplay Policy Changes`, see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Other then that - it works fine https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqyzEM?editors=1000